# Making a list from user input - follow-up

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, tkinter

I have made the changes that people have suggested from my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51824/making-a-list-from-user-input).  I want to try and make it even tidier if possible.  What can I change to make it more optimized? My `import`s are quite messy and I am not sure what ones I actually need, so if you can help with that, please do.

```
#Imports
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys

class MyFileManager(object):
    def __init__(self, filename='', save_filename=''):
        self.filename = filename
        self.save_filename = save_filename


    def save_users_list(self, list_name):
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as file:
            users_list = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]

        with open(self.save_filename, 'w') as file:
            file.write('{} = {}'.format(list_name, str(users_list)))


    def get_filename(self):
        self.filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt"),
                                                        ("All files", "*.*")))


    def get_save_file(self):
        self.save_filename = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt"),
                                                          ("All files", "*.*")))

manager = MyFileManager()

#Window
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Python List Maker")
window.geometry("300x170")

#Label
file_select_label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Please select your file:")
file_select_label.pack()

#Button
filename_button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Browse", command=manager.get_filename)
filename_button.pack()

#List Name
list_name_label = tkinter.Label(window,text="Please enter what you want to call the list:")
list_name_label.pack()
list_name = Entry(window)
list_name.pack()

#Save List
save_list_label = tkinter.Label(window,text="Please select where you want to save the list:")
save_list_label.pack()
save_filename_button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Browse", command=manager.get_save_file)
save_filename_button.pack()

#Go
go_button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Go!", command=lambda: manager.save_users_list(
                                                                    list_name.get()))
go_button.pack()

#Main Loop
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The PEP8 document I linked to in my answer on your previous question has [a section around imports](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) and how you should structure them. Some of the main points:

```
# This is ok.
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksavefilename

# System libraries, then 3rd party, then local
import sys
import tkinter
import mymodule
```

As a general guideline, it is not prudent to do: `from module import *`. This is because that single line imports **ALL** submodules in a module which, depending on how large the module is, can pull in **a lot** of extra, not needed stuff.

Now, I will not tell you which imports you don't need, mainly because I feel that the 'how' and 'what' ideas behind `import`s is something best learned on your own with some light prodding and guidance. I will say this, these two import statements are equivalent:

```
import tkinter
tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(...)

from tkinter import askopenfilename
askopenfilename(...)
```

Using the above ideas, you'll find you have a few not-needed imports. Also, a quick search-and-find in a text editor will show another import that is not needed (HINT: search for `showerror`).

As another rule of thumb: import only what you need and be as specific as is prudent.